# Building a gradle repository

Tags: maven, repository, gradle, ivy

I just want to know whether I have to use a maven or ivy repo or whether gradle offers its own repository management in some way? I thought that using maven or ivy repos in gradle was just to tide you over to a new build system and that you can eventually forego ivy and or maven.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle currently doesn't offer its own repository format. That is, you forego Maven and Ivy on the client side, but you'll still use a Maven or Ivy repository. I strongly recommend to go with a repository manager such as Artifactory (my favorite) or Nexus.

Comment: Artifactory does look verry impressive and the interface looks superb. Is there a free version available or is it paid for only?

Comment: There is a free version, and it's quite powerful. For example, last time I checked, even LDAP support was in the free version. Artifactory also has special Gradle support that goes beyond a standard Maven/Ivy repository.

Comment: Excellent. Artifactory it is for now. Really don't want to muck about with ant and ivy manually to build a repo.